# getting structure name return each time only first contact given name. android

Tags: android

hi frnds i want to fetch all the given name in contact list but each time when i cal l this method it returns first value of contact  list in each time pls take a look  below in my code below. how to i read next value when getName(long _id) method call each time....

```
public String [] getName(long _id)
{
    String Given = null ;
    String family = null ;
    try {
        String whereName = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);

        if(cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {  
                // This would allow you get several email addresses  
                // if the email addresses were stored in an array  
                Given = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                // family = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(Given != null)
                    break;
            }
        }       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("test", "Exception " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.deactivate();
            cursor.close();             
        }
    }
    //return emailid;
    //return emailType;

    Log.i("RETURN given name.....", Given);   
    return new String[] { Given};       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as u posted it won't work in any case. You cannot declare a variable in a `try{}` block and use it in the `finally{}` block. But let's talk about your question first.

Looking at your code I see that u never make any use of the _id parameter thus always getting the same name. You need to check whether the id of the current row is the same as the id you get as parameter in `getName(long _id)`. Something like this should do:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                if (cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName._ID)) == _id) {
                    Given = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Hopefully this helps!

And remember to put at least the declaration for `cursor` before the `try{}` block :)

Comment: +1 right answer but actually i got the same  issue ...any way thanks ..:) happy coading

Comment: what is the issue that u still have?

Comment: one of  the issue i still have that when i am  fetching the "Display Name " from contact list it display all  the contacts with Email means email address are also coming when i am sending .csv file(containing columns name and contact number) to  emailid so i am worried how it is fetching email from my emailid and display in column of name in .csv file?

Comment: code is : for fetchin contact name :displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)).trim();

Comment: well I do not get the same behaviour. DISPLAY_NAME only gives me the display name. I'm on android 2.1 on an emulator. If u are still having  troubles please post a new question with a detailed description of your issue.